# CPU affinity issue using Python API for MOSEK

Tags: cpu, affinity, mosek

I am having an issue with CPU affinity and linear integer programming in [MOSEK](http://www.mosek.com/).  My program parallelizes using the `multiprocessing` module in `Python`, thus MOSEK is running concurrently on each process.  The machine has 48 cores so I run 48 concurrent processes using the `Pool` class.  Their documentation states that the [API is thread safe](http://docs.mosek.com/7.0/capi/The_optimizers_for_continuous_problems.html#sec-solve-parallel).

After starting the program, below is the output from `top`.  It shows that ~50% of the CPU is idle.  Shown is only the first 20 lines of the top output.

```
top - 22:04:42 up 5 days, 14:38,  3 users,  load average: 10.67, 13.65, 6.29
Tasks: 613 total,  47 running, 566 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 46.3 us,  3.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 49.2 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem:   503.863 total,  101.613 used,  402.250 free,    0.482 buffers
GiB Swap:   61.035 total,    0.000 used,   61.035 free.   96.250 cached Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
115517 njmeyer   20   0  171752  27912  11632 R  98.7  0.0   0:02.52 python
115522 njmeyer   20   0  171088  27472  11632 R  98.7  0.0   0:02.79 python
115547 njmeyer   20   0  171140  27460  11568 R  98.7  0.0   0:01.82 python
115550 njmeyer   20   0  171784  27880  11568 R  98.7  0.0   0:01.64 python
115540 njmeyer   20   0  171136  27456  11568 R  92.5  0.0   0:01.91 python
115551 njmeyer   20   0  371636  31100  11632 R  92.5  0.0   0:02.93 python
115539 njmeyer   20   0  171132  27452  11568 R  80.2  0.0   0:01.97 python
115515 njmeyer   20   0  171748  27908  11632 R  74.0  0.0   0:03.02 python
115538 njmeyer   20   0  171128  27512  11632 R  74.0  0.0   0:02.51 python
115558 njmeyer   20   0  171144  27528  11632 R  74.0  0.0   0:02.28 python
115554 njmeyer   20   0  527980  28728  11632 R  67.8  0.0   0:02.15 python
115524 njmeyer   20   0  527956  28676  11632 R  61.7  0.0   0:02.34 python
115526 njmeyer   20   0  527956  28704  11632 R  61.7  0.0   0:02.80 python
```

I checked the [MOSEK parameters](http://docs.mosek.com/7.1/pythonapi/Parameters.html) section of the documentation and I didn't see anything related to CPU affinity.  They have some flags related to multithreading within the optimizer.  These flags are set to `off` as default, and when redundantly setting it to `off` there is no change.

I checked the cpu affinity of the running python jobs and many of them are bound to the same cpu.  But, the weird part is I can't set the cpu affinity, or at least it appears to be changed again soon after I change it.

I picked one of the jobs and set the cpu affinity by running `taskset -p 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF 115526`.  I do this 10 times with 1 second in between.  Here is the cpu affinity mask after each `taskset` call.

```
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 10
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 7
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 800000000000
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 800000000000
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 200000000000
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 800000000000
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
pid 115526's current affinity mask: 800000000000
pid 115526's new affinity mask: ffffffffffff
pid 115526's current affinity list: 0-47
```

It seems like something is continually changing the cpu affinity during run time.

I have also tried setting the cpu affinity of the parent process, but it has the same effect.

Here is the code I am running.

```python
import mosek
import sys
import cPickle as pickle
import multiprocessing
import time

def mosekOptim(aCols,aVals,b,c,nCon,nVar,numTrt):
    """Solve the linear integer program.


    Solve the program
    max c' x
    s.t. Ax <= b

    """

    ## setup mosek
    with mosek.Env() as env, env.Task() as task:
        task.appendcons(nCon)
        task.appendvars(nVar)
        inf = float("inf")


        ## c
        for j,cj in enumerate(c):
            task.putcj(j,cj)


        ## bounds on A
        bkc = [mosek.boundkey.fx] + [mosek.boundkey.up
                                     for i in range(nCon-1)]

        blc = [float(numTrt)] + [-inf for i in range(nCon-1)]
        buc = b


        ## bounds on x
        bkx = [mosek.boundkey.ra for i in range(nVar)]
        blx = [0.0]*nVar
        bux = [1.0]*nVar

        for j,a in enumerate(zip(aCols,aVals)):
            task.putarow(j,a[0],a[1])

        for j,bc in enumerate(zip(bkc,blc,buc)):
            task.putconbound(j,bc[0],bc[1],bc[2])

        for j,bx in enumerate(zip(bkx,blx,bux)):
            task.putvarbound(j,bx[0],bx[1],bx[2])

        task.putobjsense(mosek.objsense.maximize)

        ## integer type
        task.putvartypelist(range(nVar),
                            [mosek.variabletype.type_int
                             for i in range(nVar)])

        task.optimize()

        task.solutionsummary(mosek.streamtype.msg)

        prosta = task.getprosta(mosek.soltype.itg)
        solsta = task.getsolsta(mosek.soltype.itg)

        xx = mosek.array.zeros(nVar,float)
        task.getxx(mosek.soltype.itg,xx)

    if solsta not in [ mosek.solsta.integer_optimal,
                   mosek.solsta.near_integer_optimal ]:
        print "".join(mosekMsg)
        raise ValueError("Non optimal or infeasible.")
    else:
        return xx


def reps(secs,*args):
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < secs:
        for i in range(100):
            mosekOptim(*args)


def main():
    with open("data.txt","r") as f:
        data = pickle.loads(f.read())

    args = (60,) + data

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(reps,args=args))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code unpickles data I precomputed.  These objects are the contsraints and coefficients for the linear program.  I have the code and this data file hosted in this [repository](https://github.com/nickjmeyer/cpuAffinityMCVE).

Has anyone else experience this behavior with MOSEK?  Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: @ali_m I'm running it from the shell.  The jobs are currently running and I've just been trying to tweak it as its running.  I found the parent process ids using `ps -o ppid=103841` and then ran the same `taskset` command on those, but the result is the same as before.  The cpu usage actually starts to rise if you watch `top`, but then  quickly falls back to ~50%.  So it looks like setting the parent cpu affinity works, but only for a couple seconds.

Comment: @ali_m I added the code snippet that starts the child processes and waits for them to finish.  I also included the output of `pstree -s 103841` in the question.  Here it is as well `init───screen───bash───python───python───2*[{python}]`

Comment: @ali_m no worries about sounding repetitive.  I'm happy to make sure.  I posted an image of the htop output showing the tree.  When hitting "A" on PID `103785` it shows all cpus selected.  When hitting "A" on PID `103841` only 1 cpu is selected.  I tried running `taskset -p 0xffffffffffff 103785` and again for `103841`.  I checked htop after running both and the affinity for `103841` showed all selected, but after checking back in a few seconds it went down to a single cpu.

Comment: @ali_m If I highlight all of them, then the cpu affinity in htop shows all cpus.  But when isolating some of the children they are bound to a single cpu.

Comment: Hmm, I've never come across that sort of behavior before. Maybe it is MKL-specific - it might be interesting to try to reproduce this using a version of numpy that isn't linked against MKL. Could you turn this into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (you might be able to replace `wrapper` etc. with some trivial functions in order to illustrate the problem)? In the meantime I will tidy up some of my comments where you've added the details to your question already.

Comment: @ali_m I have a MCVE.  Though it doesn't appear to be a numpy issue.  (I had assumed it was since so many people have had issues with it).  It ended up being a [Mosek](http://www.mosek.com) issue.  I have the code hosted as a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nickjmeyer/cpuAffinityMCVE).  The Mosek documentation says the [API is thread safe](http://docs.mosek.com/7.0/capi/The_optimizers_for_continuous_problems.html#sec-solve-parallel).  Should I post the code here and revise the question?  Or do you suggest I make a new post?

Comment: Glad you managed to narrow the issue down. If I were you I would edit this post to reflect the new info and trim out any irrelevant details above. Be sure to update the title as well. I'm not familiar with MOSEK, so I doubt I'll be able to offer any more help here. Good luck!

Comment: @ali_m  Will do.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted support, and they suggested setting `MSK_IPAR_NUM_THREADS` to `1`.  My problem takes fractions of a second to solve, so it never looked like it was using multiple cores.  Should have checked the docs for default values.

In my code, I added `task.putintparam(mosek.iparam.num_threads,1)` right after the `with` statement.  This fixed the problem.